# How to set up a DMZ on a Sky Hub

Tags: router

Is it possible to set up a DMZ for my home server on a "Sky Hub" router? I'm trying to secure my home server so that I can safely use it for FTP, minecraft, plex etc. outside of my home network.

I can't seem to find the option anywhere!

Comment: What's the exact model of the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it possible to set up a DMZ for my home server on a "Sky Hub" router?

You can do this on the WAN Setup page.

For the SR101 and SR102:

[image]

Source [WAN Setup for the BSkyB SR101Router Sceenshot](http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/BSkyB/SR101/WAN_Setup.htm)

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised that only one DMZ server is allowed!

Comment: @BenAdamson I'm not. It's a Sky branded box with custom firmware more than likely ;) I suppose you could put your own router behind the Sky box and put that in the DMZ. Then do what you need to on the second router ...

Comment: So is this the preferred method to use if you need to use the *Sky SR102* to connect to Sky's fibre (due to their propriety connection protocol) but you still want to use a third party router for your main DHCP and WiFi functionality?